# Scrolling not working on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, scroll, overflow

For some reason i am unable to scroll down on both the iPad and the iPhone with overflow: scroll on this website..
http://gottadvita.is/spurtogsvarad

I have been trying to fiddle with the overflow and height css on the html, body and .subpage, but that has born no results.

Thanks

Comment: you have some javascript dynamically applying height to the body tag. what scripts are you using

Comment: skrollr.js is used on the main page. I'll try and remove it, i can see why it's silly on this page. I got this codebase a couple months ago and have been wrangling with it ever since :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I just notice opening the page on a desktop is that the page has two scroll bars. The iPad's scroll function is probably linked to the outer of the two, not the inner, which actually scales with your expanding text. Can you rebind the function of the inner scroll bar to the outer, and remove the inner?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand what you mean. Do you mean applying overflow: hidden to the body and leaving the inner?

Comment: I figured this out, thanks to [@ashley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1193072/ashley). Essentially, skrollr.js was messing with the body, causing the issue [@Fruity_Grebbles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3062440/fruity-grebbles) mentioned. Once i sorted out the javascript scrolling worked perfectly!